# IE9 bug? iframe misbehaving due to URL sensitivity

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I'm seeing on my IE 9 (9.0.8112.16421) a strange behaviour whereby on changing the location of an `iframe` via javascript using `iframe.setAttribute( 'src', 'http://..' )` it throws an error in the javascript console.

At first it appears to be case related, but then confusingly I tried some other URLs with some upper-case characters and it worked.

If I use the javascript below:

```
frame.setAttribute( 'src', 'http://tidevwls03:7161/OpenTwinsApp/app/index.jsf' );
```

Or..

```
frame.src = 'http://tidevwls03:7161/OpenTwinsApp/app/index.jsf';
```

Or even hard coded HTML..

```
<iframe src="http://tidevwls03:7161/OpenTwinsApp/app/index.jsf"/>
```

Then I get the following error.

```
SCRIPT5022: DOM Exception: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5) 
core.js, line 1 character 192310
```

Strangely, if I change the OpenTwinsApp part to opentwinsapp, myapp or MyApp it works as expected. The URL `http://www.google.com:80/OpenTwinsApp/app/index.jsf` also appears to work.

As a work around; I'm considering introducing a new page for a javascript forward as providing the URL as a parameter appears to be fine. It's not ideal, but at least it would work.

Are there any other work arounds I can use?

It seems like a bug in IE 9? As usual, Chrome works immaculately.

**Updates:**

- I've tried setting the iframe src using only HTML and I also got the same error message.
- I tried introducing a forwarding page that would simply do a `document.location.href = 'http://tidevwls03:7161/OpenTwinsApp/app/index.jsf';` but this also fails to load with the same error.
- I tried using a shortened URL `http://goo.gl/Sy4pk` to access the page, it resulted in the same error.

Comment: There's no way that the hard-coded HTML version would give you a JavaScript error. You need to run a test with an un-minified version of your JavaScript code so that you can get a clearer idea of what's going on.

Comment: Why do you think that redirection failed? It's more likely that there's a problem in your target page, and that redirection works for other URLs simply because target pages don't exist. Chrome working doesn't really mean that it should work. HTML got in trouble exactly because everything worked. Problem was it started to work differently in each browser.

Comment: Have you tried re-typing it, just to make sure that a non-visible character didn't slip in through a copy-paste and hence results in "invalid character"? (Not a very likely cause, but a quick one to rule out).

Comment: @Pointy: Sadly it does, the following HTML triggers it: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="opentwins">
      <iframe id="opentwins" src="http://tidevwls03:7161/OpenTwinsApp/app/index.jsf?otInstance=Personal%A0SBS" />
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: @JonHanna: Yes, I've tried many times. No joy.

Comment: @NikolaRadosavljević: I can point IE9 directly at the URL and it works fine. No problem at all. It's just in the IFrame. I've set the response header 'X-Frame-Options' also to allow the content in an IFrame.

Comment: @Pointy: I forgot to mention. The javascript core.js is not my code, it appears to be part of the browser.

Comment: It could be the content of the page I am loading, but it's hard to know what is offending it. Any idea how I could find out?

Comment: What can you see via the IE developer tools?

Comment: Interestingly, I changed the document mode to Quirks. It began to work then. In IE 8 standards mode it appears to work correctly, including my tooltips which Quirks mode breaks. I just need to work out the doctype for IE8 standards mode now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appeared to be because of IE9 Standards mode. I changed to Quirks mode and the IFrame content would load. In my instance I wanted to change to IE8 Standards Mode so that the tooltips would also work over input elements and the iframe.

The following link was especially helpful in helping me to understand what needed to be done to get the browser into IE 8 Standards Mode - [Activating Browser Modes with Doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/)

In the end I added a doctype of `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">` and then added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">` to get the IE browser to emulate IE 8.